# Why does jupyter notebook append long list of ^@ symbols to end of ipynb file?

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook

About a year ago I noticed that when I tried opening my python notebooks I had saved on a university server I got a “Notebook does not appear to be JSON” error. At first I was shocked and dismayed that all my hard work was gone forever, but when I inspected the file in emacs I saw that it was all there except that the end of the life contained a long list of ^@ symbols, which confused the JSON interpreter (example below).

[image]

Simply deleting these ^@ symbols restored the file. Since then every time I get this JSON error (which is fairly often) I just open emacs and delete the symbols, but it’s getting annoying.

Can anyone explain to me why this happens and can it be prevented? As far as I can tell, this only happens when I work on ipynb files from a server that my personal laptop (MacBook Pro OS X 10.12.6) is connected to via smb. It never happens when the ipynb files are stored locally. I just prefer working from the server because everything is automatically backed up and sometimes I use different computers, so I always have access to my files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is corrupted. The `^@` means the ASCII `NUL` byte. Simply what has happened is that the file was *extended* to some larger size; the metadata was flushed to disk, but the actual contents remained in the cache when the computer (accidentally) shut down or the operating system crashed, or the USB drive was removed.

I.e. in your case, you probably *did* lose your latest edit to this file.

Comment: I know the file is corrupted, and I know how to fix it (just delete all the ^@). There was no crash or USB drive removed and I don't loose any data when this happens. I simply save all my work, close jupyter notebook, then close the server connection. When I reconnect to the server and open my files, sometimes they have the ^@ symbols, and sometimes they don't! So my question is, how do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: You close the connection abruptly. Perhaps flush the filesystem caches before closing the connection!

Comment: Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Please pardon my ignorance, but how do I flush the filesystem caches? I am on Mac OS Sierra. Is it some terminal command?